# If the dragon balls in DBGT were those made by Dende, how could a shadow dragon be born in them after Oolong wished for an underwear in DB?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-gt

1. In Dragon Ball GT, we are told that the negative energy that popped out of the dragon balls of the earth was created as a result of wishes that were made since the beginning of the **Dragon Ball** series. For example, a shadow dragon was formed when Oolong wished for underwear.
2. In Dragon Ball Z however, we know that the earth's dragon balls were gone after Kame fused with Piccolo, later in Cell Saga Goku brought Dende on Earth who became the next guardian of the earth and made new dragon balls.

Aren't those two events or sets of events contradictory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In episode 192 of DBZ; as Piccolo points out that since the new dragon was made out of the model of the old one so their powers must be linked. Well that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Dragon Ball GT is not canon, the events are not created in conditional writing to each other. Sorry to say, but there is no better answer to this. It is the reason why Dragon Ball Super was aired.